# How to update a table row containing fullcalendar events using php

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to update event details from fullcalendar events.When event is clicked,a modal pops up with a form to add more details to the already existing event.But i cant seem to figure out how to call the id of the specific event row from my events table using php
heres my update code

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$numb = $_POST['numb'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE rsvp SET name='$name',email='$email',numb='$numb' where id='$eventid' LIMIT 1");
```

Ive done it with ajax,but now i need to try it out with php.Please dont downvote,im on a mission to learn as much as possible as best as i can.

In Ajx i got the id as follows

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: 'process.php',
                        data: 'type=changetitle&title='+title+'&name='+name+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&eventid='+event.id,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',.....
```

How do i get the event id using php then update my event table with more details?

Comment: You're submitting a `GET` paramter, just do `data: {type: 'value', etc: 'etc', }` and while you're at it. Add this '`<title>MySQL Injection Test Tool</title>`' to  the `<head>`.

Comment: data: {type: 'value', etc: 'etc', } can only be applied to ajax and jquery.How do i get the event id using php?i want to use php not ajax.  $eventid = $_POST['eventid']; then where id='$eventid'...this is not working...and when i remove the where clause in my php it updates all the rows instead of the row id/eventid

Comment: Do I have to repeat myself again? `{submit: true, eventid: event.id, etc: 'etc'}`

Comment: where do i apply this?in my form submit button or my php file?

Comment: In your `$.ajax` call, replace `data: 'this string'` with that value.